# App begin to crash on iOS 9.1 with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I was using Parse with iOS 8.4 and Xcode 6.4 successfully. The parse version which I was using 1.7.5. Recently, I have updated my pods to latest and parse version is now 1.9.1 and also project settings to compile for 9.1. Secondly, I am using Xcode 7 now.

Everything compiles good and build is successful. However, when I am trying to run the application I get below error.

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFACL
  Referenced from: /Users/ankur/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5924BE2D-5302-4140-B9C1-4E1D671B3C1F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9C046EDE-986D-4A6E-B461-38D7F859F5C7/myapp.app/myapp
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/ankur/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5924BE2D-5302-4140-B9C1-4E1D671B3C1F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9C046EDE-986D-4A6E-B461-38D7F859F5C7/myapp.app/myapp

I looked for PFACL and it is part of PODS. I can find it under PODS.

Not sure what is wrong here but looks like something missing?

Thanks for the help
Ankur

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for so long and unable to receive an answer, I posted this on Parse Git page here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/526#issuecomment-154668196. After getting a response, I investigated further and found that earlier version was able to run without **[Parse enableLocalDatastore]** however with newer version the moment I put that extra line of code the app is running perfectly. Though there are no errors while compiling the app in both cases.

I thought to share it here with the community so in case someone else face the similar problem it is helpful for them to try it.

Thanks for helping, the problem is sorted

Ankur